# Strange double-to-string conversion

Tags: android, double

I am using the following code to populate a Spinner in one of my Activities...

```
    for( double i = 0; i < 10 ; i+=0.1 ) {
        rVoltsList.add( Double.toString( i ) );
    }
    Spinner rVoltsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.recloseVoltsSpinner );
    ArrayAdapter<String> rVoltsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, rVoltsList );
    rVoltsSpinner.setAdapter( rVoltsAdapter );
```

I was assuming this would give me a list as follows : 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, and so on.
However, this is what the list looks like when I run my program:

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.79999999999999999999
0.89999999999999999999
0.99999999999999999999
1.09999999999999999999
1.2
1.3
and this goes on until 9.99999999999999999998
```

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving decimal places over in a double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937402/moving-decimal-places-over-in-a-double)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
rVoltsList.add( String.format("%.1f", i) );
```

The problem is that `Double.toString(i)` will not round.

The strange values are due to the fact that 0.1 (base 10) does not have an exact representation as a `double` in Java, so every time you add it to the loop variable, you are adding something a bit different than what you think (if you'll pardon the pun).

The same issue of rounding suggests that you should not be using a `double` as a loop variable. You are very unlikely to exactly hit your loop limit exactly. I would rewrite your loop as follows:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 100 ; ++i ) {
    rVoltsList.add( String.format("%.1f", i / 10.0) );
}
```

Comment: This works, but I don't understand....if I am only adding 0.1 to the value of i, how does it get those strange values?

Comment: @JuiCe - The issue is that arithmetic with doubles is generally not exact. In particular, the (base 10) value 0.1 does not have an exact representation in binary. Thus, the last bit or two of the sum will be off. This rounding error often gets worse the more times you add 0.1 to a number.

Comment: @JuiCe - Because of the same issue of rounding errors in floating point calculations, you should modify your loop to use an `int` loop variable and computing `i / 10.0` inside the loop. The problem is that you cannot easily predict which side of 10.0 you'll land on in the last iteration (after one hundred additions of not exactly 0.1). From the way you wrote the loop, it looks like you don't want that 9.99999999999999999998 value (after rounding to 10.0).

Answer (score 2):

```
DecimalFormat dtime = new DecimalFormat("#.#"); 

for( double i = 0; i < 10 ; i+=0.1 ) 
{   
    String i2= Double.valueOf(dtime.format(i));
    rVoltsList.add( Double.toString( i2 ) );
}
```

Comment: If this approach is used, the declaration of `dtime` should be moved out of the loop. There's no need to create a new `DecimalTime` each iteration.