# How to add picker to insert amount?

Tags: android, insert, selection, picker

i need to add a picker in my activity that allows to insert a double value, with minimum 0,2 and step 0,01. Something like this:

[image]

I tried to search on Android documentation and i found these:

[image]

Is it possible to suit Android picker to my purpose? Does exist anything better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227073/using-numberpicker-widget-with-strings

Comment: Can i use NumberPicker with double values? Or should i use 2 NumberPicker widgets? If i should, how to put the decimal point?

Answer (score 1):

This post might be of help:
[Getting float/double from NumberPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464571/getting-float-double-from-numberpicker)

Although I think the best route is to just use a Spinner, see this post:
[Strange double-to-string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209328/strange-double-to-string-conversion)