# How to round 0.745 to 0.75 using BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP?

Tags: java, bigdecimal, rounding

I tried the following,

```
   double doubleVal = 1.745;
   double doubleVal1 = 0.745;
   BigDecimal bdTest = new BigDecimal(  doubleVal);
   BigDecimal bdTest1 = new BigDecimal(  doubleVal1 );
   bdTest = bdTest.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
   bdTest1 = bdTest1.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
   System.out.println("bdTest:"+bdTest); //1.75
   System.out.println("bdTest1:"+bdTest1);//0.74    problemmmm ????????????
```

but got weird results. Why?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `.setScale` as a better way to round than the mysteriously inscrutable `.round(MatchContext...)` bs.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Never construct BigDecimals from floats or doubles. Construct them from ints or strings. floats and doubles loose precision.

This code works as expected (I just changed the type from double to String):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String doubleVal = "1.745";
  String doubleVal1 = "0.745";
  BigDecimal bdTest = new BigDecimal(  doubleVal);
  BigDecimal bdTest1 = new BigDecimal(  doubleVal1 );
  bdTest = bdTest.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
  bdTest1 = bdTest1.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
  System.out.println("bdTest:"+bdTest); //1.75
  System.out.println("bdTest1:"+bdTest1);//0.75, no problem
}
```

Comment: This also works fine without going to strings if you use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`, the static factory method which is preferred over the constructor (noted in the javadocs.)  Using `BigDecimal bdTest = BigDecimal.valueOf(1.745); BigDecimal bdTest1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.745);` gives the same result (0.75)

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg didn't you mean `BigDecimal.valueOf("0.745");` instead of `BigDecimal.valueOf(1.745);` ??? ... maybe not, there is no such `BigDecimal.valueOf(String)` :-/

Comment: Yes, the key to the comment is the lack of quotes.  From the javadoc of `BigDec.valueOf(double)`:   _"Note: This is generally the preferred way to convert a double (or float) into a BigDecimal, as the value returned is equal to that resulting from constructing a BigDecimal from the result of using Double.toString(double)."_

Comment: What if my `BigDecimal` is imported with `@ConfigurationProperties` from Spring? I can't control how it's constructed from `application.yml` which supposely already provides the value as a `String` and still ends with the same rounding issue.

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg: `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` is _not_ the preferred way of constructing a BigDecimal. It is the preferred way of converting a double into a BigDecimal. The string constructor is the preferred way of constructing a BigDecimal. Per the docs: "it is generally recommended that the String constructor be used in preference to [the double constructor]"

Comment: `valueOf(double)` and `new BigDecimal(String)` have similar comments indicating they are "the preferred way.to convert a float or double..."  My read, given the comments on both constructors about "the unpredictability of `new BigDecimal(double)`" is that either of those first two are good, and the caveat is to generally avoid the latter (despite the confusing "the").

Answer (score 13):

```
double doubleVal = 1.745;
double doubleVal1 = 0.745;
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(doubleVal));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(doubleVal1));
```

outputs:

```
1.74500000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875
0.74499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
```

Which shows the real value of the two doubles and explains the result you get. As pointed out by others, don't use the double constructor (apart from the specific case where you want to see the actual value of a double).

More about double precision:

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937402/moving-decimal-places-over-in-a-double)
- [there](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 10):

Use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double d)` instead of `new BigDecimal(double d)`. The last one has precision errors by float and double.

Answer (score 3):

This will maybe give you a hint on what went wrong.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal bdTest = new BigDecimal(0.745);
        BigDecimal bdTest1 = new BigDecimal("0.745");
        bdTest = bdTest.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        bdTest1 = bdTest1.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        System.out.println("bdTest:" + bdTest); // prints "bdTest:0.74"
        System.out.println("bdTest1:" + bdTest1); // prints "bdTest:0.75"
    }
}
```

The problem is, that your input (a `double x=0.745;`) can not represent 0.745 exactly. It actually saves a value slightly lower. For `BigDecimals`, this is already below 0.745, so it rounds down...

Try not to use the `BigDecimal(double/float)` constructors.

Answer (score 2):

For your interest, to do the same with `double`

```
double doubleVal = 1.745;
double doubleVal2 = 0.745;
doubleVal = Math.round(doubleVal * 100 + 0.005) / 100.0;
doubleVal2 = Math.round(doubleVal2 * 100 + 0.005) / 100.0;
System.out.println("bdTest: " + doubleVal); //1.75
System.out.println("bdTest1: " + doubleVal2);//0.75
```

or just

```
double doubleVal = 1.745;
double doubleVal2 = 0.745;
System.out.printf("bdTest: %.2f%n",  doubleVal);
System.out.printf("bdTest1: %.2f%n",  doubleVal2);
```

both print

```
bdTest: 1.75
bdTest1: 0.75
```

I prefer to keep code as simple as possible. ;)

As @mshutov notes, you need to add a little more to ensure that a half value always rounds up. This is because numbers like `265.335` are a little less than they appear.

Comment: You can get unexpected result. For example: Math.round(265.335 * 100) / 100.0 != 265.34 See comments to http://stackoverflow.com/a/153753/2664193

Answer (score 0):

various option are available such as:

```
 Double d= 123.12;
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(d, MathContext.DECIMAL64); // b = 123.1200000
b = b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);  // b = 123.12

BigDecimal b1 =new BigDecimal(collectionFileData.getAmount(), MathContext.DECIMAL64).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)  // b1= 123.12

 d = (double) Math.round(d * 100) / 100;
BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(d.toString());  // b2= 123.12
```