# Java: Calculations returning wrong answer?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retain precision with Doubles in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java)
>   [Moving decimal places over in a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937402/moving-decimal-places-over-in-a-double)

For example, something as simple as this:

```
public class WrongAnswer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(100*1.1);
  }
}
```

prints 110.00000000000001 instead of 110.  Using other numbers instead of 100*1.1 also give a lot of digits with some random digit at the end that isn't right..

Any ideas?

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of floating point numbers, where everything is approximate and the decimals don't matter.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+double+precision

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Floating point notations have limited degrees of accuracy. Here's a guide: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 4):

Most floating point calculations involve rounding errors. In your case, there are two rounding errors: converting (decimal) 1.1 to floating point (there's no exact representation for 1.1 in IEEE 754 floating point--which is what Java uses) and then multiplying by 100. See the excellent article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

In `100*1.1` the `1.1` is not qualified and so by default is `double` while `100` is by default `int`.
So the result of the multiplication is also `double` due to the upcast of `100` and that is why you get this result.

Comment: The cast to `int` happens to work here, but only by accident. In other contexts you could end up with one less than you expect.

Comment: 100.0d * 1.1d gives same result (110.00000000000001)

Comment: but float no problem :) 100.0f * 1.1f   (110.0)

Comment: It is certainly not 'due to the upcast of 100'. The fact that 100 is an int isn't even relevant. As one of the operands is a double, the calculation is always going to be carried out as double.

Comment: @EJP:In order for the calculation to be carried as `double` *both* operands should be double and that means that `100` first is *converted* to a `double` as a result of `binary numeric promotion`.And I did not say this is due to `upcast of 100`.But due to `1.1` being `double` and therefore `100` being widened to carry out the multiplication.Please read more carefully if you plan to downvote

Answer (score 0):

As answered, it becomes double hence the format. To print the `closest int/long` value, better to use `Math.round()` function as :

```
 System.out.println(Math.round(100*1.1));
```

This becomes important when you are multiplying with more precise numbers e.g.

```
    System.out.println(Math.round(100*1.199));  //--> prints 112
    System.out.println((int)(100*1.199)); //--> prints 111
```

Comment: @NegativeUser: Please leave some comment to understand the issue.