# float variable wrong answer

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Calculations returning wrong answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020297/java-calculations-returning-wrong-answer)

Please explane why following program not giving correct output.

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String aa[])
    {
        float a=16.15 f;
        float b =10.0f;

        float c =a-b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

/****************/
Out Put:-6.1499996

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: floating points calculations can't results in exact precision for .15.

Comment: There should be some canonical standard answer for this type of questions, no day passes without a dozen of 'em :-(

Comment: When using floats, add an error margin epsylon, and check for c < epsylon.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with floats themselves, rather than your code, as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point_standard

For this case, consider either using `double`s or `BigDecimal`s

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfectly normal consequence of floats not being able to store *decimal* values exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Because floats, being base-2 cannot exactly represent 16.15 and therefore the result of the subtraction is not exactly -6.15.

Answer (score -1):

The type `float` does not have good enough precision to return -6.15. `double` may not be enough either, floating point computations always have some margin of error.

Comment: It's a question of which base it is in