# Java iterator in double value

Tags: java, math, loops, double, iteration

I am trying to iterate the value of I from 1 to 0 or from 0 to 1. But I have got some problem.
Please check the following codes:

```
double i = 1.0;
loop{  // Just use a loop to iterate the i. This is just a pseudocode. 
       // We can use while-loop or for-loop or timer. 
       // (I know there is no keyword "loop" in java)

   i -=0.1;

   if( i == 0.0){
     // stop the loop
   }
}
```

In the above code, the loop will never stop because when the variable i will become 0.7000000001 when i = 0.8 - 0.1 during the loop. i will have lots of decimal number when i = 0.1 - 0.1. so it will never equal to 0.0.

I apologized if my description of my question is not clear enough for you.
This may be a very easy question for pro programmers. But I cannot figure it out. Please let me know what I have done wrong.

Comment: `if (i <= 0)` will eventually end - but it might loop 10 or 11 times depending on precision. More about double (lack of) precision: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937402/moving-decimal-places-over-in-a-double

Comment: Your concern is correct. But what is your concrete question?

Comment: You can't represent a floating point value exactly using `double` or `float`. So `0.1` and `1.0` that you are using is not exact representation. You should rather use `BigDecimal` to get exact representation of floating point numbers.

Comment: @assylias Is correct, it loops 11 times and then gets to 0. But I don't quite understand the question either.

Comment: @WilliamShatner.. No, it will not get to `0`. It will get to value less than `0`.

Comment: @RohitJain Sorry, I meant then it gets below 0.

Comment: @RohitJain: You can absolutely represent a floating point value exactly using `double` or `float` - they're floating point types. But the "point" here is a *binary* point. `BigDecimal` is also a floating point type, but the point is a decimal point.

Comment: @JonSkeet.. Sorry, but I couldn't understand. As far as I know, floating point values are not stored as base 2. So, they could not be represented exactly. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: @JonSkeet. And the line that confused me in your comment is: - `But the "point" here is a binary point.`? What does that mean?

Comment: @RohitJain: It means that `double` and `float` are *floating binary point* types. `BigDecimal` is a *floating decimal point* type. So for example, the *decimal* number 0.5 (i.e. half) is 0.1 in binary, and can be represented exactly. "Floating point" is just any representation which uses two integer values: a *mantissa*, and an *exponent* to shift the "point" around.

Comment: @JonSkeet.. Ok. So, you mean that when we have value `0.5` in `double`. The number after decimal is converted to binary, and it is not the case with `BigDecimal`? Did I get it right? Can you post some good source where I can read about them in detail?

Comment: @JonSkeet.. Ok, I just got a link. I think that is a good one for this topic. -- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @JonSkeet.. I saw your [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4937424/1679863) where you said `double simply can't represent a number like 0.1 exactly`. And now I'm confused. `0.1` is a floating point number right?

Comment: thank you all. I think I have got what I want from the discussion above and the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you like to iterate from 1...10 and divide current value by 10?
Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
   double value = (double) i / 10d;
}
```

Or if you don't void to have precision issues you can use BigDecimal:

```
BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.ZERO;

for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
   value = value.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1d));
   double doubleVal = value.doubleValue();
}
```

Comment: actually all answers here have taught me what I haven't known and solved my problem. However, yours is the clearest. I appreciated that.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend BigDecimal usage. 
I know BigDecimal is used in financial systems, and not Double or Float, to describe exact numbers with decimal dots (i.e - prices).

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)

Answer (score 0):

Use integers for iteration and scale them appropriately.

```
i = 10;
while (i != 0)
{
    double d = i / 10.0;
    // do stuff with d

    i--;
}
```

This will work even if the scale factor is not representable in decimal.

Using `BigDecimal` will only work with decimal fractions. If for example you want to iterate by steps of one third it won't work.