# BigDecimal to string

Tags: java, string, bigdecimal

I have a BigDecimal object and i want to convert it to string.
The problem is that my value got fraction and i get a huge number (in length) and i only need the original number in string for example:
for

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(10.0001)
System.out.println(bd.toString());
System.out.println(bd.toPlainString());
```

**the output is:**

```
10.000099999999999766941982670687139034271240234375
10.000099999999999766941982670687139034271240234375
```

and i need the out put to be exactly the number `10.0001` in string

Answer (score 146, accepted):

To get exactly `10.0001` you need to use the String constructor or `valueOf` (which constructs a BigDecimal based on the canonical representation of the double):

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("10.0001");
System.out.println(bd.toString()); // prints 10.0001
//or alternatively
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(10.0001);
System.out.println(bd.toString()); // prints 10.0001
```

The problem with `new BigDecimal(10.0001)` is that the argument is a `double` and it happens that doubles can't represent `10.0001` exactly. So `10.0001` is "transformed" to the closest possible double, which is `10.000099999999999766941982670687139034271240234375` and that's what your `BigDecimal` shows.

For that reason, it rarely makes sense to use the double constructor.

You can read more about it here, [Moving decimal places over in a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937402/moving-decimal-places-over-in-a-double)

Comment: A more efficient way of converting a `double` this way is to use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double);`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Not sure I understand. `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` "rounds" the double in the same way doubles get rounded when printed, which uses somewhat complex rules so I'm not sure how you can rely on that.

Comment: `Translates a double into a BigDecimal, using the double's canonical string representation provided by the Double.toString(double) method.

Note: This is generally the preferred way to convert a double (or float) into a BigDecimal, as the value returned is equal to that resulting from constructing a BigDecimal from the result of using Double.toString(double).`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes I know that. I just don't know how predictable it is that `Double.toString(double)` will return the expected result. For example, `Double.toString(99999999.21110999)` returns `99999999.21111`...

Comment: That is true but in that situation using the constructor won't help either, you have to use rounding.

Comment: this answer dosent really answer the question as to how to convert a BigDecimal to a String.

Answer (score 14):

Your `BigDecimal` doesn't contain the number `10.0001`, because you initialized it with a `double`, and the `double` didn't *quite* contain the number you thought it did. (This is the whole point of `BigDecimal`.)

If you use [the string-based constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) instead:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("10.0001");
```

...then it will actually contain the number you expect.

Answer (score 14):

For better support different locales use this way:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
df.setGroupingUsed(false);

df.format(bigDecimal);
```

also you can customize it:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");
df.format(bigDecimal);
```

Answer (score 9):

By using below method you can convert java.math.BigDecimal to String.

```
   BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("10.0001");
   String bigDecimalString = String.valueOf(bigDecimal.doubleValue());
   System.out.println("bigDecimal value in String: "+bigDecimalString);
```

**Output:**
bigDecimal value in String: **10.0001**

Answer (score 1):

```
// Convert BigDecimal number To String by using below method //

public static String RemoveTrailingZeros(BigDecimal tempDecimal)
{
    tempDecimal = tempDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
    String tempString = tempDecimal.toPlainString();
    return tempString;
}
```

---

```
// Recall RemoveTrailingZeros
BigDecimal output = new BigDecimal(0);
String str = RemoveTrailingZeros(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you just need to set precision quantity and round the value, the right way to do this is use it's own object for this.

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("10.0001");
value = value.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(value); //the return should be "10.0001"
```

> One of the pillars of Oriented Object Programming (OOP) is "encapsulation", this pillar also says that an object should deal with it's own operations, like in this way:

Answer (score 0):

The BigDecimal can not be a double.
you can use Int number.
if you want to display exactly own number, you can use the String constructor of BigDecimal .

like this:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("10.0001");
```

now, you can display bd1 as 10.0001

So simple.
GOOD LUCK.

Answer (score 0):

To archive the necessary result with double constructor you need to round the BigDecimal before convert it to String e.g.

new java.math.BigDecimal(10.0001).round(new java.math.MathContext(6, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)).toString()

will print the "10.0001"