# Right way to convert of BigDecimal to String

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Why I should use `valueOf()`?
why cant I use the implicit conversion?

Code Snippet is shown below:

```
BigDecimal xmlvalue = new BigDecimal(12.3434379328948927894789237);
String str1 = String.valueOf(xmlvalue); //Option 1
String str2 = "" + xmlvalue; //Option 2
```

Comment: What's the problem with option 2? Why can't your use it?

Comment: Why not **String str = xmlvalue.toString()**?

Comment: Check below link
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900204/bigdecimal-to-string>

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`BigDecimal#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString%28%29) to convert a BigDecimal to string

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `toString()` method

```
xmlvalue.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think better way is to use class - `java.text.DecimalFormat` because in practical scenarios , there is no relation between actual value represented by these number classes like `BigDecimal` & their String representations, though you haven't listed your reason for wanting a String value for an altogether different type of data.

In my opinion, String representation is all about formatting & this `DecimalFormat` class gives you better control over that e.g. I needed to write few `BigDecimal` values to a text file and different values needed to be in different format.

A portion of Java Doc,

> DecimalFormat is a concrete subclass of NumberFormat that formats
>   decimal numbers. It has a variety of features designed to make it
>   possible to parse and format numbers in any locale, including support
>   for Western, Arabic, and Indic digits. It also supports different
>   kinds of numbers, including integers (123), fixed-point numbers
>   (123.4), scientific notation (1.23E4), percentages (12%), and currency
>   amounts ($123). All of these can be localized.

Answer (score 1):

One could argue that it is more readable to use `valueOf(x)` than `"" + x`. Internally, both will fall back to `toString` but they can also deal with null values (where `null.toString()` will throw a `NullPointerException`).

In theory, the performance of `valueOf(x)` should be better than `"" + x`, as the latter uses a `StringBuilder` internally, which can lead to some overhead.

**When you know that your `BigDecimal` is non-null (as in your example), you should just use `toString`.**

By the way, be careful with the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor. The safer approach is to use 
`new BigDecimal("12.3434379328948927894789237")` in your example. The reason why `BigDecimal(double)` is unpredicable is explained in [its Javadoc comment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29).

Answer (score 1):

For two reasons:

1. Using `String.valueOf` better conveys your intent: you obviously try to get the String representation of a BigDecimal value; abusing String concatenation requires a little more mental effort to understand what you are trying to do
2. It may be faster: Using concatenation will internally create a StringBuilder, which concatenates two Strings and then calls toString() onto itself (though the compiler may be clever enough to get rid of these unnecessary operations)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you ever manually use `"" + string` for a conversion to String? I know that a lot of developers use that, but to me it seems just like taking an advantage of Java's developer friendliness and the fact that it does a lot of stuff(terminus technicus "conversions") automatically. In other words it's a lazy way around and I don't like raping Java when `String.valueOf()` is implemented exactly for this purpose.

**Technical answer:**

When `a + ""` is used with an integer `a`. It behaves as such:

```
String.valueOf(a) + new String("");
```

This creates two String objects, while `String.valueOf(a)` uses just one.

Comment: You are technically correct, but then you'd have to assume that the creation of two object is actually a problem. Which it is not, Java is an object creation and cleanup performance beast. Better let it deal with the optimizations of what happens under the hood and focus on what is readable code primarily. EDIT: which might mean that your advice is still valid, but for different reasons!

Answer (score 1):

Using BigDecimal doesn't bring back the precision lost in `double` If you need more than 15 digits of accuracy you need to use String and BigDecimal.

```
BigDecimal xmlvalue = new BigDecimal("12.3434379328948927894789237");
String str1 = xmlvalue.toString(); // Simplest Option
```

If you have a `double` you may as well just do

```
// creating BigDecimal here doesn't help unless you do rounding.
String str1 = String.valueOf(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

The String#valueOf use [Double#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28%29) method in this case.

I think is better use [BigDecimal#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString%28%29) method. For example if you want to converted back this data, it better use this toString method.

> If that
>   string representation is converted back to a BigDecimal using the
>   BigDecimal(String) constructor, then the original value will be
>   recovered.