# ConvertString to Big Decimal in JAVA

Tags: java, string, bigdecimal, numberformatexception

I am trying to store a String into a column with datatype Big Decimal.

```
String a = transaction.getBeneAmt();
log.info(a);
tran.setTransAmt(new BigDecimal(transaction.getBeneAmt()));
tranRepository.saveAndFlush(trangloTran); //save into database
```

But I get

```
2017-07-05 18:04:19 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  ApiController - IDR 3,000,000.00
2017-07-05 18:04:19 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:494)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:383)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:806)
```

Comment: John, you really want to convert **Big Decimal to String**? As I'm able to see in your code that you are trying to convert **String to Big Decimal**

Comment: How much of your log entry is the value of `a`? (Does it include the IDR?) I don't think BigDecimal can handle thousands separators though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900204/bigdecimal-to-string Similar Question.

Comment: @MayankJain post updated.

Comment: I get value `IDR 3,000,000.00`. No idea why will get `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`

Comment: @Andreas: NumberFormatException != NullPointerException.

Comment: Well why did you expect `BigDecimal(String)` to be able to parse that? Did you expect it to just remove the leading "IDR " part? Does the documentation suggest it will do that?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, sorry, I just noticed that too, and was about to undo it, but you did it for me. Thanks.

Comment: "The string representation consists of an optional sign, '+' ( '\u002B') or '-' ('\u002D'), followed by a sequence of zero or more decimal digits ("the integer"), optionally followed by a fraction, optionally followed by an exponent." Basically, this is behaving as documented - if you pass in a value which doesn't follow the expected format, it throws NumberFormatException.

Comment: @JonSkeet so it is impossible to store Big Decimal with IDR xxxxx ?

Comment: @John yes, it won't be possible.

Comment: @John `BigDecimal` is for *numbers*, e.g. `3000000.00` is a valid number. `3,000,000.00` is not a valid number for `BigDecimal`. The [Indonesian Rupiah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_rupiah) `IDR` currency prefix is not a valid part of a *number* either. So no, `BigDecimal` cannot store an **amount** value with currency.

Comment: Well yes, `BigDecimal` is a number. Where does "IDR" fit into that? You can store the *numeric* part of course - you'll want to strip off the "IDR" and remove the commas.

Comment: @John, did you tried solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3752616/5059727) but that will not help you to store **IDR**

Comment: thanks guys ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your String contains alphabetic characters so it won't be possible to convert it to `BigDecimal`, that's why you got `NumberFormatException`.

You need to replace these alphabetic characters before trying to convert it:

```
String a = transaction.getBeneAmt();
log.info(a);
tran.setTransAmt(new BigDecimal(a.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z,]", "").trim()));
tranRepository.saveAndFlush(trangloTran);
```

Comment: Still won't work, since `" 3,000,000.00"` is not a valid value for [`new BigDecimal(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-java.lang.String-).

Comment: @Andreas Yes I missed the `,` part. Thank you I edited the answer