# Error summing double numbers

Tags: java, android, floating-point, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving decimal places over in a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937402/moving-decimal-places-over-in-a-double)

I have a problem in my android application using double variables. An `EditText` parses a number, a double, and puts it in sql database. When I extract that value and I sum with other values the result is incorrect.

For example:

- I write and put in my db this: 64.1
- another value: 12.6
- another value: 400

then I sum these 2 values and the result is 476.70000000000005 wich is incorrect (should be 476.7).

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You can declare the result value(Adding three value) to float..

Comment: This is not a problem in your code, it is a problem with your expectations of floating-point arithmetic.  There are many many questions, and answers, on SO about this topic.  I suggest you review some of them.

Comment: @Subburaj How is using float going to solve a precision issue?

Comment: @assylias anyway it will cut the precision value to some extent..

Comment: [This article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) may interest you. Also using `BigDecimal` is good way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

use this function:

```
double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
            DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```