# Java Double Trouble

Tags: java, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving decimal places over in a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937402/moving-decimal-places-over-in-a-double)

**Code :**

```
    public class Teste {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Exponent loop:");
            for(int i=1; i<10; ++i)
               System.out.println(Math.pow(0.1, i));

            System.out.println("\nMultiplication loop:");
            double a = 1;
            for(int i=1; i<10; ++i){
               a *= 0.1;
               System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

Exponent loop:

```
0.1
0.010000000000000002   
0.0010000000000000002    
1.0000000000000002E-4    
1.0000000000000003E-5    
1.0000000000000004E-6    
1.0000000000000004E-7    
1.0000000000000004E-8    
1.0000000000000005E-9
```

Multiplication loop:

```
0.1    
0.010000000000000002    
0.0010000000000000002    
1.0000000000000003E-4    
1.0000000000000004E-5    
1.0000000000000004E-6    
1.0000000000000005E-7    
1.0000000000000005E-8    
1.0000000000000005E-9
```

Comment: the results look correct. what exactly is your question?

Comment: Duplicate of many questions. Is there one standard answer to this question?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin 1.0000000000000002E-4 != 1.0000000000000003E-4

Comment: `pow` doesn't perform iterative multiplication, so it's no surprise that sometimes the result is slightly different.

Comment: Don't use `pow` if you can avoid it. It's expensive and can produce significant rounding errors.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: perhaps better than saying the results look "correct", we should say that the results look "as expected".

Comment: Dear OP, I suggest you read this, so understand what's going on behind the scenes of your code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: Two words: "epsilon rounding"

Comment: Instead of multiplying by `0.1` and cannot be represented exactly, try dividing by 10 instead (10 can be represented exactly)

Comment: @JuniorWate Perhaps you should explain why this is not possible ;)

Comment: @JuniorWate The link I posted contains everything you need to know. 0.1 * 0.1 is internally **rounded** to 0.0100[...]2 and when you print it, you see the rounded value

Comment: Try running `System.out.println("0.1 is actually " + new BigDecimal(0.1));
    System.out.println("0.1 * 0.1 is actually " + new BigDecimal(0.1).pow(2));
    System.out.println(" and the closest double value is " + new BigDecimal(0.1).pow(2).doubleValue());`