# Modulus data validation (.05 increments, Think nickles, dimes, quarters, etc...)

Tags: java, validation, modulus

Working on a simple java program that should only accept an input that is in .05 cent increments. When attempting to use the mod operator for data validation, I am getting some weird, unexpected results:

```
        public static void takePayment(double itemCost){
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    System.out.println(itemCost);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please insert $" + df.format(itemCost) + " into the machine");
    System.out.println("Type the amount you are inserting into the machine.");
    System.out.print("$");

    if (!input.hasNextDouble()){
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount inserted in X.XX format");
        takePayment(itemCost);
    }
    double amtInsert = 0;
    amtInsert = input.nextDouble(); 
    double remainder = 0;

    remainder = amtInsert %(0.05);
    System.out.println(remainder);

    if (remainder == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("works");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid amount inserted, this machine only accepts Nickels, Dimes, Quarters, "
                + "1 dollar bills, and 5 dollar bills ");
        takePayment(itemCost);
    }


}
```

If a dollar amount such as 1.25 is entered into the function, it returns:

```
Please insert $1.25 into the machine
Type the amount you are inserting into the machine.
$1.25
0.04999999999999993
Invalid amount inserted, this machine only accepts  Nickels, Dimes, Quarters, 1 dollar bills, and 5 dollar bills.
```

Can someone explain why `(1.25 % .05) = 0.04999999999999993`

***Keep in mind while reading my code that I haven't written the rest of the validation, I am only concerned with the modulus at the moment***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937402/moving-decimal-places-over-in-a-double

Comment: Round the value to two decimal places if you need precise values

Comment: You can solve this by counting cents instead of dollars - you can then store them in an `int` or `long` which will give exact results.

Comment: If you'd like to rephrase your question to ask why that doesn't evaluate to 0, then I'll reopen it. However, other modulo calculations online return `0.05`, so you may want to look up the calculation that's really being done

Comment: I got it figured out. Thanks for pointing me to the other thread, it helped me solve it!